# How to correct split UT from IT tests on spring-boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have spring-boot application, and UT and Integration tests.
So, I customized @Caterogory for split UT from IT-tests.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
</plugin>
```

I marked UT as @Category(UnitTest.class) and integration tests by @Category(Integrations.class)
So, to start only UT or IT test I can execute

```
mvn test -Dgroups="ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.UnitTest"
mvn test -Dgroups="integration.Integrations"
```

But, in I start my application by using

```
mvn clean package
```

All my tests will be launched and integration tests will failed.

I tried to add in plugin

```
                <configuration>
                    <groups>UnitTest</groups>
                </configuration>
```

Butm after this, my command

```
mvn test -Dgroups="integration.Integrations"
```

every time starts only UT, not IT

How to configure, that clean package execcute only UT, and 
mvn test -Dgroups="integration.Integrations" after this starts only integration tests?

Comment: Simply name the tests accordingly. Unit test `*Test.java` and integration test with `*IT.java` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise if I will use this patterns, how to launch ut and it from command line?

Comment: See the [docs of maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) and you could use it like this: `mvn test -Dtest=MyTest` or more complex patterns are supported. Why running unit tests from command line and not just simply `mvn clean test` to run all UT's ? Furthermore I would strongly recommend to use maven-failsafe-plugin to run your integration test...which can be used to run a it's via command line if you need it like this: `mvn -Dit.test=MyIT verify` etc.

Comment: BTW: I realized that you are using a spring boot app so you should follow the conventions of Maven name your tests accordingly. Never overwrite plugins versions in your own pom file. Are you using the parent or are you inside a multi module build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mvn clean package -Dgroups="UnitTest"
So, just execute package with addition param.